# Spring data rest, java.util.Date in url param?

Tags: java, spring, rest

I have a simple POJO named as `Check`. And I have a simple rest repository:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "check",path = "check")
public interface RestCheckRepo
        extends JpaRepository<Check,Integer> {

    public List<Check> findByShopName(@Param("shop") String shop);

    public List<Check> findByDateTime(@Param("dt")Date dt);

    public List<Check> findByShopNameAndDateTime(@Param("shop")String shop, @Param("dt")Date dt);

    public List<Check> findByShopNameAndDateTimeBetween(@Param("shopName") String shop,
                                                        @Param("start")Date t1,
                                                        @Param("end") Date t2);


}
```

All works fine!! But I don't know how to implement a request handler using `java.util.Date` as a `@RequestParam`.
Example: http://localhost:8080/check/search/findByDateTime?dt={value}

**UPDATE**
Request
http://localhost:8080/check/search/findByDateTime?dt=2015-08-10T13:47:30
---> Response:

```
{
    "cause": {
        "cause":null,
        "message":null
    },
    "message":"Failed to convert from type java.lang.String to type @org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param java.util.Date for value '2015-10-07T15:04:46Z'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException"
}
```

Comment: My guess is you need to parse it as java.sql.Date not as java.util.Date

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Solution of @kucing_terbang will work, otherwise there is a simpler solution, you need do this:

```
public List<Check> findByShopNameAndDateTime(
    @Param("shop")String shop, 
    @DateTimeFormat(your-format-comes-here)@Param("dt")Date dt);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can register a custom editor so that spring able to pass the parameter to the argument. example

```
@InitBinder
public void dataBinding(WebDataBinder binder) {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    dateFormat.setLenient(false);
    binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, "dob", new CustomDateEditor(dateFormat, true));
}
```

Comment: Ummm, where did you add this method? Surely not to the ```RestCheckRepo``` interface, right? And there's no controller, since the point of ```@RepositoryRestResource``` is to avoid the need for a controller. Maybe inside some ```@Configuration``` annotated class?

BTW, is this thread-safe? I know that ```SimpleDateFormat``` by itself is not.

Comment: I would choose to use `@ControllerAdvice` annotated class. I am not so sure whether it is gonna work if you use `@Configuration` annotated class. As for the thread safety, looking at the java doc of `DataBinder` class, I would say it is thread-safe. I mean, if it is not safe, then the doc would state it. But you probably want to test this to make sure of it.